# Flutter get keyboard key virtual code [Windows]

Tags: flutter

How to get a virtual key code(According to msdn table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) of a pressed keyboard key in Flutter?

There is a RawKeyEvent.logicalKey.keyId property, but it represents some other ID, not Windows'

Also, flutter has [KeyCode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/KeyCode-class.html) class, but it works only on Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RawKeyEvent event; (Typically retrieved by FocusNode onKey function)
RawKeyEventDataWindows data = event.data as RawKeyEventDataWindows;
print(data.keyCode);
```